# url rewriting in Struts1

Tags: struts

I am developing a web application using Struts1 as web framework. My url pattern in web.xml is:

```
<servlet-mapping> 
<servlet-name>action</servlet-name> 
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

I want to get rid of `.do` pattern in urls. So if my url is

http://localhost:38330/MyProject/editFunction.do?function=1

i want it to be like http://localhost:38330/MyProject/editFunction/ . How do I acheive this type of url rewriting ? 
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You can use a filter before calling the struts request processor, and this project it's very helpful: http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

Comment: I know about this project. I would like to know if it is standard? Does it have any issues?

Answer (score 0):

You can map your `<url-pattern>` to allow prefix, like

```
<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>/action/*</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then if you do (e.g.) http://localhost:38330/MyProject/action/editFunction/, your struts action will be called (if mapped correctly on `struts-config.xml`).